# Method to cycle subflows

Tags: visual-workflow

The user enters the flows from a Home Page link, or a VF page.
I have Flow A which has subflow B.
SubFlow B has Subflow C

Once someone has completed SubFlow C, I want them to return to Subflow B. When I try this I get the error below.

"The Flow has a subflow which returns to a Parent Flow. Cycles of subflows are not allowed."

Is there anyway to achieve the above? Because the default behavior brings them back to Flow A, this creates a problem and an error.
I also tried to get creative and throw in Subflow D which someone would go to From C and D would then route them to B but got same error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run it from the design editor? I found [here](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/06/subflows-in-visual-workflow.html) that only the parent is able to be embebed on a VF page. Although this is an older article, and maybe it's not true on latest release, it worth to take a look first.

Not sure why you are getting this issue, never had before. But a workaround could be to create a subflow D that would be a twin of B and this can be called from C, in case you don't need a loop, a mean, A - B - C - B - C - B - C .... it could be A - B - C - D.

Please, post the solution if you find it. It's a very interesting question.

Comment: It doesn't matter where its launched from, yes its same from design editor. The article you reference is still true but a slightly different issue. It's to avoid endless loops so I understand the basic why but it also prohibits any loops at all. I'm sure creating a duplicate flow, which is what looks like you are proposing, would work but that's a drastic workaround and not that maintainable.

Comment: Agree, drastic workaround, and I would look for another option before applying it.

Comment: Hello! Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple - add the "End flow and open URl" Action element at the end of the screen flow and use the URL for the flow to open it in a new window

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Is this a hypothesis or do you have direct experience where you have done this and it worked? Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/378389/edit) your answer to add that information.

Comment: And lets be clear. The question was from 9 years ago or 27 Salesforce releases. What's "simple" now clearly wasnt so when Obama was just starting his 2nd term. As the original poster, I can say I haven't seen this error, just using the standard subflow options avail, in many years.